# The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value - Leap Year

Tags: sql

I get this error in stored procedure code and I discovered one of the records is from a leap year date 2008-02-29. How do I get around this with the code I have. Here is the code:

```
set @ContractDate = cast(cast(@Year as nvarchar(4))
+ '/' + cast(datepart(mm,@ContractDate) as nvarchar(2))
+ '/' + cast(datepart(dd,@ContractDate) as nvarchar(2)) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 2):

First off:

- What values do you have for @Year and @ContractDate?
- And what format/type is @ContractDate?

I ask because this works for me on `us_english` SQL Server 2012

```
SELECT cast('2008/02/29' as datetime)
```

However, if I change `SET DATEFORMAT` then I can break the above code

```
-- breaks
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT cast('2008/02/29' as datetime)
```

Using ISO date format is OK *no matter* what I use for SET DATEFORMAT

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT cast('20080229' as datetime);
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
SELECT cast('20080229' as datetime);
SET DATEFORMAT YDM;
SELECT cast('20080229' as datetime);
```

Conclusion: you are using non ISO date formats and relying on implicit conversions

Comment: There aren't any values set for either. I've done a separate query where I set @Year=2012 and ContractDate = '2008-02-29 00:00:00.000' but I don't have it set in the stored procedure.  Not sure what you mean about what format ContractDate is? Do yo mean datatype?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to get the string in ISO format (`yyyymmdd`) before converting to datetime/date and it will work in any server regardless of culture settings

If `@ContractDate` is a *`datetime/date`* type and `@year` is like *`2012/'2012'`* then following should work. [**Working Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9234)

```
Set @ContractDate = convert(datetime,
  convert(varchar(4),@year) + right(convert(varchar(8),@ContractDate,112),4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sden_report1]
@fromdt nvarchar(13),
@todt nvarchar(13)

AS

BEGIN 
select AD_PID,AD_Appointmentdate,AD_Patientname,AD_Patientphno,AD_Visitpurpose
from Appointment_Details1
where 
--PL_CID = @CID and PL_Itemcode = @JCode AND
(@fromdt = '' OR (DATEDIFF(DAY,AD_Appointmentdate, @fromdt) <= 0))
AND (@todt = '' OR (DATEDIFF(DAY,AD_Appointmentdate, @todt) >= 0))
end


GO

When i Execute the procedure
i will get below error:

EXEC Sden_report1 '20-11-2012','20-05-2013'

Error
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Anyone Help...`enter code here`
```